# Why to use $emit now that $broadcast overperforms it?

Tags: angularjs

Now that `$broadcast` is almost 7x faster than `$emit`, there are reasons to use `$emit` instead of only to use `$rootScope.$broadcast`?

Why is not good to use `$rootScope` in all your controllers now that `$scope` use is transparent, except to handle events?

Am I totally wrong with that concept?

Comment: I know it, but why cannot to use $rootScope for all? $rootScope.$broadcast and $rootScope.$on? You're not answer  my question my friend.

Comment: `$scope` is the foundation of Angular's data binding. I wouldn't call it "almost useless".

Comment: @nickgraef Yes but it is almost transparent. I edit my question.

Comment: where is this data that "`$broadcast` is almost 7x faster than `$emit`" coming from? unless something drastically changed that I haven't seen, the performance of these event functions are still based on the number of scopes, child scopes, direction, etc.

Comment: also, I'm not understanding what you are saying "`$scope` use is transparent?"

Comment: @Claies You don't need  to inject $scope in all your controllers.

Comment: are you referring to using the Controller As syntax?

Comment: http://jsperf.com/rootscope-emit-vs-rootscope-broadcast/76 it is obviously a dummy benchmark but, what benchmark is not dummy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong with this situation.  Using `$rootScope` as an event bus *can* work, but it's not a simple black and white performance decision.

Changes to `$broadcast` in [Angular 1.3.0-beta19](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#130-beta19-rafter-ascension-2014-08-22) allow for `$broadcast` to [exit early if nobody is listening to the given event](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/a09fa356416c033a52666f3becf00524ecff3a03).  This doesn't automatically mean that `$broadcast` is more efficient than `$emit`, only that it doesn't run with no listeners, while `$emit` still will.  This makes it appear to be faster, in the [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/rootscope-emit-vs-rootscope-broadcast/76) you reference in your comments.

`$broadcast` dispatches events downward from the `$scope` to all child scopes (and their children).  With even one listener, `$broadcast` from `$rootScope` is going to hit **every** scope in your application.

`$emit`, on the other hand, bubbles events upwards.  Since `$rootScope` is the topmost scope, `$emit` on `$rootScope` will always touch exactly one scope.  If you MUST use `$rootScope`, `$emit` will be better.

Using `$rootScope` has it's own problems, however; If you register a listener from a controller, you will need to manually remove the listener when your controller is destroyed.  Controllers are not singletons, and multiple controllers which create a listener and then are destroyed without removing the listener will eventually create a memory leak in your app.

Using a global event bus can also be a problem, as it's relatively easy for multiple components to try to register the same event, or trigger an event that they aren't responsible for, creating subtle bugs that can be very difficult to find.

In general, it's best to use `$broadcast` from a scope to it's descendants as close to the bottom of the tree as possible.  Only services should use `$rootScope`, as they do not have access to other scopes.  In that case, `$emit` is better, as it reduces the number of scopes touched to 1.  However, Almost all cases of cross controller communication can be better managed with correct scope hierarchies that rely on bindings rather than events.